# Simple HTML <div> is not padding the width of it's contents

Tags: html, css, google-app-engine

I have what is probably a very simple question, but I'm fairly new to HTML developement (I know I'm about 20 years late on this), and I'm having a issue.

I have the following code:

```
<div style="padding:10px; background-color:#b0c4de;">   
  <img src="SOME_IMAGE_URL_HERE">
</div>
```

Now, my `SOME_IMAGE_URL_HERE` is a URL string inserted via **Python** (on Google AppEngine) at runtime, and the image itself can vary in size. I would like my `div` to surround the image with a `10px` padding, kind of like providing a box around the image.

The code above provides a `10px` padding on the top and bottom, but the `div` stretches across the entire width of the screen. How can I set the `div` width to that of the image? Keep in mind, the image size changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a `display` property of `inline-block`. [Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/7mt6h/)

(You could also `float` it to the `left` and a handful of other things, but `inline-block` is the least likely to cause other problems.)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I'll accept in 4 minutes when SO allows me to.